# How can I create user profile and authenticate using phone and user password on flutter firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

There isn'y enough documentation on this subject. so I'm looking for some experiences from amazing people out here.

We need the main sign in method in the app to be using phone number as user name and user chosen password, Phone will be verified with OTP upon registration and when resetting password.

Flutter offers sign in using phone verification, as far as I know each time user has to go through OTP. I need the user to set a password and only verify phone once at signup or when resetting password.

also we wanna link the credentials to a firestore user profile (name, job, email, etc). How would we do that?

Code for sign in using email:

```
CustomMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    try {
      final UserCredential _userCredential =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _user.email, password: _user); //_user is a custom made class that has user profile data
      if (_userCredential != null) Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.screenId);
    } catch (e) {
      showCustomSnackBar(context, e.message);
    }
  },
  text: "Log in"),
```

code for sign up:

```
CustomMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    try {
      final UserCredential _newUserCredential =
          await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _user.email, password: _user.password);
      if (_newUserCredential != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, VerifyPhoneScreen.screenId);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showCustomSnackBar(context, e.message);
    }
  },
  text: "New user signup"),
```

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSSyK.png)

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWiju.png)

[Screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq5yY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once a user is signed in to Firebase Authentication (whether with phone number or another method of signing in) they stay signed in, unless you either explicitly sign them out, or a compelling event (such as changing their password, disabling their account) happens.

As long as you [listen to auth state changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state), the app should reflect the user's sign-in state. If you're having trouble making this work in your app, edit your question to [show that you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added screenshots. Signup on 3 steps(1-mail&pass 2-phone verification 3-profile data).
what's needed is to save verified phone on the user profile so user can use it to reset password besides email .. and link all this to one user.

Comment: Please read the link to [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I gave, as screenshots of your app are only useful if we're discussing layout issues. For a problem like this, we'll want to see the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks Frank .. I have added the code used to create user using email and password .. How can I link that to phone number if that's possible .. Also 'User' class in firebase has 'displayName' field .. how can I use that to store user name .. better question would be: Is it possible to store more profile info using User class (if user profile data are so basic) .. or is only way to store user profile data is to link uId to fireStore document with profile details.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You've posted a lot of questions in there, and I just answered the "as far as I know each time user has to go through OTP" one: if you use an auth state listener, the user won't have to sign in each time. As far as I can see, most of your other questions have been answered before, so I recommend searching for those separately - and taking a first try at implementing those use-cases yourself based on previous questions/answers.

Comment: Thanks .. but it hat I meant was that the user will have to sign in through OTP each time the user signs in (I know firebase has persistence on on default) .. what I meant was that phone verification through OTP can be a one time process while sign up or requesting password reset .. other than that, user might just sign in using phone number and password .. as in facebook for instance .. you can sign in with phone number as username and password .. you can request OTP in case you forgot password

Comment: This username/mail/phone from my small search looks like a subjective matter .. apple has disabled using phones and custom usernames .. I was wondering if firebase auth has that option

Comment: I really appreciate your effort